# How can I split textbox value and store it in two string variable c#

Tags: c#

I have a sample textbox `txtAddress` and I want to save it on two string `address1, address2`. if `txtAddress` is more than 15 character the other character will store in `address2`.
example:

```
txtAddress = 'how can i save this string'
```

storing should be, `address1='how can i save, address2= ' this string'`

i try this code but i dont know how to split using delimiter of number of character

```
txtAddress.Value= "how can i save this string";
  Char delimiter = 15;
  String[] substrings = txtAddress.Value.Split(delimiter);
  foreach (var substring in substrings)
```

Thanks in advance, hope you can help me guys.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) might help you acheive it as this method extracts strings. It requires the location of the substring (a start index, a length). It then returns a new string with the characters in that range.

```
string txtAddress = "how can i save this string";
if(txtAddress.Length >= 15)
{
    string address1 = txtAddress.Substring(0, 15);
    string address2 = txtAddress.Substring(15);
    Console.WriteLine(address1 + " -#- " + address2);
}
```

Comment: Hope that you missed few things, this code wont compile. could you please take a look?

Comment: From the question it is clear that `txtAddress` is a Textbox it doesn't contains definition for `Substring()`, you should use its `.Text` property(or `.Value` according to the type of textbox that you are using) to get the Text from it

Comment: Okay @un-lucky I got your point. Lemme fix that with another way.

Comment: I store the value of textbox and use this code and it works, thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal approach would be using different textboxes for address1 and address2. Anyways, you can split the string using [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. For example:

```
string s = "address1, address2";
  Char delimiter = ',';
  String[] substrings = s.Split(delimiter);
```